# PyCharm warning for type of split argument

Tags: python, pycharm

```
path  # string containing a path to a directory
lst   # list of filenames expected to be in the directory

[file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.split('_')[0].split('-')[0] in lst]
```

There is a warning in the `'-'` part saying:

> Expected type 'Optional[bytes]', got 'str' instead

Why is it happening? How to fix it?

It just happens in the second split, the first split doesn't trigger any warnings.

Comment: What lst is. dictionary ? if so what are keys and what are values ?

Comment: it is a list of strings

Comment: This warning can be ignored but can you post screen shot here to help me see this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fixed in 2020.1 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17420, first EAP build will be available by the end of January.